# Windows Command Line: CD & Execute Python

Tags: python, windows, command, cd

I'm having trouble executing a python script from Windows 7 Command Prompt. I've tried many different commands to run the script. Whether it's:

```
python e:\filepath\pythonScript.py
python pythonScript.py
cd\ & pythonScript.py
cd\ && e:\filepath\pythonScript.py
```

I keep getting the same:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Whenever I use the command:

```
dir
```

It prints the contents of the c: drive even when I use:

```
cd c: && dir
```

If anyone could shed some light on changing directories and executing python scripts in Windows 7, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: when you type "dir", do you see your python script?

Comment: I see the directory that the script is in, but not the actual file itself. I get an output like: `05/02/2012   11:59PM   <DIR>    Apps` with about 7 more directories listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about changing to a new drive just type the drive letter followed by colon

```
C:\>e:
E:\>dir


Volume in drive E has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9016-4EF8

 Directory of E:\
18-Apr-14  02:16 AM    <DIR>          assets
01-May-14  04:22 AM    <DIR>          store
06-Jun-14  09:32 AM                22 test.py

E:\>cd assets


E:\assets>python test.py
hello world
```

or

```
C:\>e: && cd assets && dir
 Volume in drive E has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9016-4EF8

 Directory of E:\assets
```

or

```
  C:\>e: && cd \  && cd assets && dir
       ^     ^          ^           ^
ch drive && go root&&go fldr && list foldr contents
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought you needed `cd` before the drive letter, but I was mistaken.